# Focus ring inconsistency when icon on right

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have the following problem. I have input and on left on it I want to have icon. Everything looks fine until I focus on the input. In such case right border (probably shadow in fact) seems to be smaller than other ones (no idea why?)

Code for this is:

```
  <div class="m-10">
  <label class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
      Password
  </label>
  <div class="mt-1 relative rounded-md flex">
      <input type="password"
              class="flex-1 appearance-none block w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-l-md focus:ring-cyan-500

          focus:outline-none sm:text-sm">

      <span class="inline-flex items-center px-3 rounded-r-md border-l-0 border border-gray-300 bg-gray-50 text-gray-500 sm:text-sm cursor-pointer">
            Some icon
      </span>
  </div>
```

However when I switch order of elements (first icon and then input and switch some classes) then on focus it looks fine.

So the questions are:

1. How to fix it (without changing markup much as it's simplified comparing to real usage scenario)
2. Why border seems to be different on focus
3. Why switching order of elements make the difference

[Working example comparing 2 cases on TailwindPlay](https://play.tailwindcss.com/vXInZBNd0m)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it by adding the class `relative` to the input.

The outline ("border") is actually the same in both examples. In the second example, the icon element covers the outline. As you can see in [this interactive example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index), elements that appear later in the dom, are "higher" than the elements before them.

Adding `position: relative;` activates `z-index` automatically and puts the element on top of the elements around it.

> z-index will only work on an element whose position property has been explicitly set to absolute, fixed, or relative

[The Z-Index CSS Property: A Comprehensive Look](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/#:%7E:text=The%20z%2Dindex%20property%20determines,to%20the%20display%2C%20or%20viewport.)